# Bijective correspondence between indecomposable modules and simple modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, representation-theory

I am trying to prove the following from Peter Schneider's book : Assuming $A$ is complete and $A/Jac(A)$ is left artinian, for a finitely generated projective indecomposable $A-$module $M$, the quotient $M/Jac(A)M$ is simple. (This generalize the assumption that $A$ is a finite dimensional algebra).

The part $Jac(A)M = Rad(M)$ follows from $M$ being projective and existence of a maximal submodule in $M$ follows from Nakayama's lemma. I am trying to prove $M$ has a unique maximal ideal. Any help?

Comment: The full reference is : Modular representation theory of finite groups, Peter Schneider.

Comment: Do you know how to lift idempotents modulo Jac(A)?

Comment: Yes. Since A complete mean it is Jac(A)-adically complete, every idempotent modulo A lifts to an idempotent in A.

Comment: Then what you need to do, essentially, is suppose that $M/J(A)M$ is not simple, so that it is decomposable, pick a nontrivial idempotent endomorphism of $M/J(A)M$ and lift it to a nontrivial idempotent endomorphism of $M$.

Comment: Sorry if I am missing something trivial : decomposable would imply not simple. Would the converse true in this scenario?

Comment: @Mariano : I got this. Jac(A)M = Rad(M) would imply Rad(M/Rad(M))=0. Since M/Rad(M) is artinian, it will be semisimple and finite length would imply only finitely many copies of simple submodules, each isomorphic to an ideal generated by an idempotent modulo Jac(A), lifting those to A, would violate indecomposibility of M. Thanks.

Comment: @Siddharta, please do write an answer giving the detailed argument, so that you can then close the question.

Comment: Write an answer in the box for answers, not as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Here it goes : M/J(A)M has a natural A/J(A)-structure which carries the finite generation property from A-module M. Since A/J(A) is left artinian, using Akizuki-Hopkins-Levinski it is left noetherian and hence M/J(A)M is of finite length. Now M is projective imply Rad(M)=J(A)P. Hence using correspondence theorem of maximal ideals Rad(M/J(A)M)=0. This implies M/J(A)M is semisimple (see Prop1.2.1(iii) ref above) with finitely many simple copies each isomorphic to A/J(A)t_i. Now using A complete lift these t_i to a mutually orthogonal system to M which is a direct sum. But M is indecomposable.

Comment: By the way the same method would work if A is I adically complete if I is contained in J(A) for the correspondence {M} -> {M/IM}.